# iphone CSS width adjustment problem

Tags: iphone, css, html

I have this page for phones which plays [music](http://bedupako.com/eradio.php)

When i open it in iphone it doesnt readjust the width to properly.

What i want is only the player to be prominently visible and other background only after displaying the player.

Currently if i readust my browser windows it adjusts properly.

Why is it not fiting into the iphone and appearin like this [image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/48d4ded308.png)

Comment: you can find the related CSS in the same page by opening the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@footy; Write

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />`

inside your head tag. Which check the viewport of the device screen and adjust according to it.

Check the **[link](http://x7.fi/2010/02/12/how-to-fit-your-website-for-the-apple-ipad/)** for more